# Как посчитать количество объектов в файле?

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Вот я записал в файл данные при помощи класса `BinaryWriter`, там всё идет по объектам. Так вот, как посчитать, сколько там объектов?

Comment: Что, куда, как записали? Код где? Сеанс телепатии чтоли? Вы хотите посчитать число байт в FileStream? Для этого можно использовать методы FileStream.Seek() & FileStream.ReadByte().

Answer (score 2):

Вместо прямой записи в файл через поток используйте сериализацию, а именно сериализируйте список с объектами и при необходимости десериализируйте обратно. После чего у списка можно просто взять *Count* и понять количество объектов.

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Это может сделать программа, **создающая** файл, а потом в каком-то виде вывести "map" созданного ей файла.

Почитайте внимательно описание методов `BinaryWriter` и вопросы отпадут.